# XPath matching text in a table - Ruby - Nokigiri

Tags: xpath

I have a table that looks like this

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
      <td colspan="9" class="csoGreen"><b class="white">Bill Statement Detail</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color: #D8E4F6;vertical-align: top;">
      <td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Bill Date</b></td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Bill Amount</b></td>

      <td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Bill Due Date</b></td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Bill (PDF)</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to create the XPATH to find this table where it contains the test Bill Statement Detail.  I want the entire table and not just the td.

Here is what I have tried so far:

page.parser.xpath('//table[contains(text(),"Bill")]')

page.parser.xpath('//table/tbody/tr[contains(text(),"Bill Statement Detail")]')

Any Help is appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first XPath example is the closest in that you're selecting `table`. The second example, if it ever matched, would select `tr`—this one will not work mainly because, according to your example, the text you want is in a `b` node, not a `tr` node.

This solution is as vague as I could make it, because of `*`.  If the target text will always be under `b`, change it to `descendant::b`:

```
//table[contains(descendant::*, 'Bill Statement Detail')]
```

This is as specific, given the example, as I can make:

```
//table[tr[1]/td/b['Bill Statement Detail']]
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I change mine up and came up with this:  ('//table/tr/td/b[normalize-space(text())="Bill Statement Detail"]/../../..'), however I like your solution more.

Answer (score 0):

You might want

//table[contains(descendant::text(),"Bill Statement Detail")]

Answer (score 0):

The suggested codes don't work well if the match word is not in the first row. See the related post [Find a table containing specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301569/find-a-table-containing-specific-text?noredirect=1#comment37559963_24301569)