# Find a table containing specific text

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a table:

```
 html ='
 <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
 <tr>
 <td colspan="9" class="csoGreen"><b class="white">Bill Statement Detail</b></td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="background-color: #D8E4F6;vertical-align: top;">
 <td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Bill Date</b></td>
 <td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Bill Amount</b></td>
 <td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Bill Due Date</b></td>
 <td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Bill (PDF)</b></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 '
```

I use the codes suggested in this post ([XPath matching text in a table - Ruby - Nokigiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202140/xpath-matching-text-in-a-table-ruby-nokigiri)). It works fine if I use any words in the first row as the match word, for example "Statement". But it doesn't work if I use words that in the other row, for example "Amount".

```
doc  = Nokogiri::HTML("#{html}")
doc.xpath('//table[contains(descendant::*, "Statement")]').each do |node|
    puts node.text
end
```

Comment: Note: `Nokogiri::HTML("#{html}")` is the same (in this case) as `Nokogiri::HTML(html)`, which is also the same as `Nokogiri.HTML(html)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contains()` function expects a singular value as its first argument. `descendant::*` may yield multiple elements then causing the function to behave unexpectedly, such as considering only the first element yielded.

Try to change your XPath to be:

```
doc.xpath('//table[descendant::*[contains(., "Amount")]]').each do |node|
    puts node.text
end
```